# The potential drop across emitter base junction is?

Tags: bjt

[image] I am unable to get the correct answer .....Messing up ..... Please help?!

Comment: Please outline your approach to the problem to let us understand where you are struggling.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it by adding your work and findings so far in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is homework with no other attempt at research or solution.

Comment: We don't just answer homework questions for lazy students.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework needs an attempt at a solution

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the transistor.

If its absolute maximum base current rating is exceeded, as seems likely with Ib>0.5A, you can assume the transistor burns out leaving only R1 and R2 in circuit, making the calculation trivial.

However, the real answer is to get a better textbook.

Comment: It not that trivial, because if the transistor burns out there is no BE junction left ;-)

Comment: No, but there are hopefully still two pins, one labelled "B" and one labelled "E"...

Comment: I'd also appreciate the \$10^3\$kΩ resistor

Answer (score 0):

If you assume high enough current amplification, i.e. you neglect the base current, then the Base voltage will be determined by the resistive divider, which sets 1V. It is an acceptable voltage for a bipolar.
Since the collector resistance is 1MOhm, the highest current what could flow is 9uA. The current flowing in the resistive divider is 0.5A, which is way more, and therefore we should not even assume anything about the current amplification.

Note: do not try this at home. It is just an exercise question, not a world class circuit.

Answer (score 0):

The \$V_{BE}\$ drop is essentially the one of a silicon diode, around 0.7 V when a couple of mA is flowing through it.

Getting 2 V requires at least tens of ampere, if not hundreds, *I believe*. Does 10 A flow through your 16 Ω resistor and then into the base of the NPN transistor? 
No, not a chance. \$\frac{9\text{ V}-0.7\text{ V}}{16\text{ Ω}}\approx500 \text{ mA}\$, this is when I'm even ignoring the 2 Ω resistor.

So 2 V, 3 V, 4V all require too much current to be realistic in this setup. The only answer that is remotely realistic is the 1 V.

Answer (score 0):

If you ignored the transistor and just looked at the potential divider formed by R1 and R2, the voltage at the base is \$9\times\frac{2}{2+16}\$ = 1 volt.

Adding the transistor will not raise this voltage but it could lower it a little bit due to the forward conductance of the BE junction. So the only answer available that makes sense is 1 volt (answer 2).